# TkInter replicate terminal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to preface this question by saying that if this counts as a "which is better?" question, I'd be happy to rephrase it to fix that.

I need to create a TkInter application that looks and functions like a basic terminal/command line, with text entry and a log of previous input and output with a scrollbar. My question is whether to use a text widget and an inputArea and just style them to look like a terminal, or whether it would be easier/better in the long run to use a canvas and go through the trouble of finding a way to allow typing into it. Any insight would be appreciated.

-Exe

Comment: it will be easier to use `Entry` or `Text` to get text.

Comment: I figured, but would it be excessively difficult, or even impossible, to format them to look like a section of a terminal?

Comment: Have a look at the source code for IDLE, it is written python using Tkinter and contains its own 'command window'.